# How to declare an array with specific indexs only once in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I am using methods to create a choose your own adventure story. One of the methods is the following:

```
 public static void storeChoices(){

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

String arr [] = new String[6];

if(arr[0] == null){
  arr[0] = "Gucci";
  arr[1] = "Tesla";
  arr[2] = "Canada Goose";
  arr[3] = "Rolex";
  arr[4] = "Saks Fifth Avenue";
  arr[5] = "Nike";
}

for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  System.out.println("  " + (i+1) + ")" + arr[i]);
}
System.out.println("Pick a number as your choice: ");

int choice = sc.nextInt();

sc.nextLine();

for(int x = 0; x < arr.length; x++){
  arr[choice] = "Dr. Java has already visited this store";
}


}
```

I want to declare the array at the beginning only once because it changes depending on the choice the user picked. Every time I call the method again, declaring the array causes any changes I made to reset. How do I declare that array only once so that when I call the method, the changes I make don't reset? I just learned a little bit of methods so I am pretty new to this.

Comment: Change from a local variable to a field

Comment: Declare it outside the method

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: That just gave me a bunch of errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not using threading mechanism then declare it as a static variable to the class

```
public class TestClass1 {

static String  arr [] = new String[6];

public static void storeChoices(){

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    if(arr[0] == null){
      arr[0] = "Gucci";
      arr[1] = "Tesla";
      arr[2] = "Canada Goose";
      arr[3] = "Rolex";
      arr[4] = "Saks Fifth Avenue";
      arr[5] = "Nike";
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
      System.out.println("  " + (i+1) + ")" + arr[i]);
    }
    System.out.println("Pick a number as your choice: ");

    int choice = sc.nextInt();

    sc.nextLine();

    for(int x = 0; x < arr.length; x++){
      arr[choice] = "Dr. Java has already visited this store";
    }


    }
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!

Answer (score 0):

In a very simplistic case, just define it as a field, and then check if null

```
public class Main {

    String [] arr = null;

    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        new Main().myMethod ();
    }

    private void myMethod () {

        if (arr == null) {
            arr = new String [] {"Gucci" , "Tesla", "Canada Goose"};
        }

    }
}
```